# Scroll behavior of two nested RecyclerViews

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two nested `RecyclerView`. One of them manages vertical swipes and one of them handles horizontal swipes. The problem I am facing is, that scrolling of the horizontal RecyclerView sometimes does not behave as expected. Sometimes it will not recognise the horizontal swipes and will just do a vertical swipe. To make the horizontal swipe it is necessary to draw a really straight line in horizontal direction. A few degrees off will be recognised as vertical swipe.Are there any parameters which can be tweaked, to make the UX better?

Outer layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:gravity="center">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb_new_home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_modules"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/newhome_recyclerview_paddingbottom" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Inner layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/NewHomeModuleContainer">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_module_title"
    style="@style/NewHomeModuleTitle" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_horizontal_recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tv_show_more"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_module_title"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-8dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingEnd="28dp"
    android:paddingRight="28dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Actually it's a bit complex, not sure if I can make that clear. But basically we have a Delegate as Adapter for the outer module, which instantiates different modules depending on the json type. Each vertical module creates another ViewHolder with a custom View and possibly another RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a self-define RecyclerView and then override `onInterceptTouchEvent` intercept touch event of the outter RecyclerView

```
boolean moveInnerRv;
private float startY;

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    float currentY = -1;
    switch(ev.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startY = ev.getRawY();
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            currentY = ev.getRawY();
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    // if move distance over 100, pass touch to inner RecyclerView
    moveInnerRv = !((currentY - startY) > 100);

    return moveInnerRv;
}
```